# Should I update VAO when I update a VBO?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

My VAO/VBO/IBO work fine on iPad and other devices on Android excepted two (A Samsung galaxy S4 and a Sony Xperia S).

A problem is present when I start my application on this devices, every elements move everywhere and start to blink on each frame, the problem is present on every element updated during the simulation.

I have a SpriteRenderer who share a VBO, so I need to update this VBO on each frame for each sprite (change color, uvs, …).

The visual glitch is not present on static element (like text).

**So my question his:**

- Did I have to do something with my VAO on each frame?

Here is what I've got:

```
Init part:

 - bind vao
     -> Bind vbo
     -> Bind ibo
 - unbind vao


Rendering part:

for( sprites )
{
     // Update (Need to bind VAO here?)
     bind vbo (lock)
     update vbo data
     unbind vbo (unlock + bind)

     // Draw.
     bind vao
     drawElement
     unbind vao
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to bind the VAO to change data in the buffers it holds pointers to, that all happens automatically. You can even re-allocate a buffer by calling `glBufferData (...)` a second time without having to setup your vertex pointers again. The vague behavior you listed sounds like a driver bug, but some more details on how `update vbo data` is implemented might shed some light on something.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks, I finally found something interesting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185609/dealing-with-opengl-es-2-0-driver-bugs): A driver problem with some devices. The only solution found is to disable VAO on Android :/